# Закрывается программа при чтении json файла

Tags: python, json, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlistwidget

Я написал программу, которая парсит новости с сайта. 
Я хочу вывести все новости в `QListWidget` после нажатия кнопки,
но у меня закрывается программа.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from guiparsing import *
from parsinggamenews import get_data_gamenews
import json


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.bth_parsinggamenews.clicked.connect(self.parsing_gamenews)

    def parsing_gamenews(self):
        with open('gamenewsresult.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
            src = json.load(file)
        self.ui.l_log.addItem(src)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**guiparsing.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'parsinggamen.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(650, 500)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(168, 168, 168);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.l_log = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.l_log.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 500))
        self.l_log.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);")
        self.l_log.setObjectName("l_log")
        self.bth_parsinggamenews = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 0, 250, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setFont(font)
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);")
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setObjectName("bth_parsinggamenews")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Parsing Game News"))
```

**parsinggamenews.py**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import lxml

def get_data_gamenews():

    a_all_card = []
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    url = 'https://www.gamespot.com/news/'
    result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
    all_cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-item base-flexbox flexbox-align-center width-100 border-bottom-grayscale--thin')
    for card in all_cards:
        card_url = 'https://www.gamespot.com' + card.find('a').get("href")
        card_title = card.find('h4', class_='card-item__title').text.replace('\"', '')
        a_all_card.append({
            'card_title': card_title,
            'card_url': card_url
        })

    with open('gamenewsresult.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
        json.dump(a_all_card, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)





def main():
    get_data_gamenews()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: я вот сразу там вижу sys.exit. Мож потому и закрывается...

Comment: Без него приложение вообще не запускается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import json
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import * 

# from guiparsing import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(650, 500)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(168, 168, 168);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.l_log = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.l_log.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 500))
        self.l_log.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);")
        self.l_log.setObjectName("l_log")
        self.bth_parsinggamenews = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 0, 250, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setFont(font)
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);")
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setObjectName("bth_parsinggamenews")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.bth_parsinggamenews.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Parsing Game News"))


# ??? from parsinggamenews import get_data_gamenews
# этот модуль вы запускаете отдельно !?


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.bth_parsinggamenews.clicked.connect(self.parsing_gamenews)

    def parsing_gamenews(self):
        with open('gamenewsresult.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
            src = json.load(file)

# ???        self.ui.l_log.addItem(src)
        print(f'{type(src)}') # 
        self.ui.l_log.clear()                                                   # +++
        for item in src:                                                        # +++
            self.ui.l_log.addItem(f"{item['card_title']}\n{item['card_url']}")  # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]